# Bind data in to TextInput from an array in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of data. Like

```
product = [
  {
    name: 'item 1',
    quantity: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 2',
    quantity: 12,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 3',
    quantity: 14,
  },
]
```

I want to show this `quantity` field in TextInput.

So how can I do that and also manage the `onChangeText` event?

Comment: So the user is looking at one of these items, and there's a text input that comes up with the corresponding quantity, which the user can edit and save? It helps if you can have a go yourself and share the code so people can see where you've got stuck. At the moment it just feels like you're asking others to do your work for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this complete example.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    product: [
      {
        name: "item 1",
        quantity: 10
      },
      {
        name: "item 2",
        quantity: 12
      },
      {
        name: "item 3",
        quantity: 14
      }
    ]
  };

  onChangeText = ( item, text ) => {
      let updateProducts = [...this.state.product]
      let index = this.state.product.findIndex(obj => obj.name == item.name)
      updateProducts[index].quantity = text;
      this.setState({
        product: updateProducts
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.product.map(item => (
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderWidth: 1, margin: 5, width: "80%", padding: 5 }}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(item, text)}
            value={item.quantity}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend for you You should read [array and list from react native documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) then you should read [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) properties finally :)
Here is working example

https://snack.expo.io/HJm8EOPr8 - react native

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        product : [
  {
    name: 'item 1',
    quantity: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 2',
    quantity: 12,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 3',
    quantity: 14,
  },
]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.product.map(item => (
              <TextInput  value={item.quantity}  /> 
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```